# How to convert text file data into html table format in linux shell scripting

Tags: shell, awk

I want to convert samplefile.txt  into  html table format.It should ignore all special characters.The start of char `###` must go into table header,while  the contents inside table header into table cell.

Also I want to format table heading and table border in this script.

This is a simple samplefile.txt:

```
###File1
###File2
###File3
###Sports
Y|Cricket|Football|basketball
Y|beach volleyball|boxing|diving
Y|cycling|Batminton|Swimming
###Country
$|United States|United Kingdom|India    
$|Peru|Japan|Poland
```

This is the script I have been working in - Somehow this code is not working 100%:

```
#!/bin/sh
tableflag=0
echo "<html>"
echo "<body>"
while read line
do
#echo $line
heading=`echo $line | cut -c-3`
headdata=`echo $line | cut -c4-`
if [ "$heading" == "###" ]; then
        #if [ $tableflag -eq 1 ]; then
                #echo "</table>"
        #fi
        echo "<th colspan="3" style="font-family: 'Times New Roman';"> $headdata </th>"
        echo '<tr>  </tr>'
        echo '<table border="1" style="width:80%;margin:30px">'
else
        tableflag=1
        echo '<tr>'
        echo "$line" | awk -F"|" '{print "<td>" $2 "</td><td>" $3"</td><td>"$4"</td>"}'
        echo '</tr>'
        echo '<tr> </tr>'

fi
done < samplefile.txt 
echo "</table>"
echo "</body>"
echo "</html>"
```

Comment: Hope i am clear now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be few issues with the script

`1) echo "<th colspan="3" style="font-family: 'Times New Roman';"> $headdata </th>"`

Here you have not escaped `"`. Correct syntax would be

`echo "<th colspan=\"3\" style=\"font-family: 'Times New Roman';\"> $headdata </th>"`

2) You are using backticks(`) to run a command.They are deprecated

heading=`echo $line | cut -c-3`

Instead use `$()`

`heading=$(echo $line | cut -c-3)`

3) I am assuming that you have print all four column in content when you split by `|`. But here you are printing only three column using awk

`awk -F"|" '{print "<td>" $1 "</td><td>" $2"</td><td>"$3"</td>"}'`

I suggest, if you do intent to print all four column, set the colspan to 4 instead of three